# Authorizing my google drive app getting invalid request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I've had a google drive app registered that's been working for years. Today customers have mentioned that they can't authorize any new users against it.

Old users who are already authorized still work fine. New users can't authorize. I thought my redirect website might be down but it doesn't appear to be. Any thoughts?  HTTP exchange is below (with identifying codes removed).

My code is implemented with the .net Google.Apis.Drive.v2 SDK (version 1.7.0.110) and supporting libs. Which I know is old but I don't think the underlying http calls it makes have changed.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token; HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 305
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

code=<VALID CODE>&client_id=<VALIDID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=<VALID SECRET>&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flicense.omtool.com%2fredirect&grant_type=authorization_code

---------

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2018 20:45:49 GMT
Server: ESF
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 33

{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Comment: Just an idea, I think you cannot make sure that everything are the same, especially that they have declared the changes in the "[Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration)" documentation. It was stated that differences between Drive API v3 and v2 are mainly changes to field names and removal of duplicate functionality. Maybe your code was affected, you need to check your calls based on the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my app has had a typo in one of the oauth urls since it shipped. It never mattered until recently. Google must have done something on their endthat made it less tolerant of the typo.

In the initial post, I have a semicolon after "token".  That was the issue.

POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token;